# Besides creating an instance, how to tell if ClassA descends from ClassB in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, prototypal-inheritance

I need to determine if one class descends (directly or indirectly) from another.

I can do

```
var testInstance : Object = new ClassA();
if (testInstance is ClassB)
    ...
```

but I hate creating an instance just to test ancestry. I hoped that if (ClassA is ClassB) would work, but it does not seem to.

AS help states

> isPrototypeOf(theClass:Object):Boolean
>   Indicates whether an instance of the Object class is in the prototype chain of the object specified as the
>   parameter.

I don't actually understand ActionScript prototypes (I think it might drive me insane), but I hope that Class objects have some way of tapping into their inheritance information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototypes are instances, either of the [class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Object.html#prototype) (for class inheritance) or the parent class (for prototype inheritance). Try:

```
Object.prototype.extends=function (theClass:Object):boolean {
    return this.prototype instanceof theClass;
}

ClassA.extends(ClassB);
```

ActionScript 3 shoehorns prototype inheritance into class based inheritance. You don't use prototypes much anymore in Actionscript, but it's not a complex concept and has its uses, so you'd do well to study it.  Read "[History of ActionScript OOP support](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f1b)" and "[The prototype object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa3)" from "[Advanced topics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3f.html)"

Comment: It looks like I would either have to modify the class (which I might not have access to) or create an instance of a class just to test its ancestry.

Thanks for the code; I will play with it.

Comment: If you don't compile in strict mode, or if the class is declared dynamic, you shouldn't need the source code to modify the class. Furthermore, you should be able to add methods to `Object` as shown, which all objects will inherit.